# How to get Remove,Repair, Uninstall Options through Install Shield using Basic MSI

Tags: installshield

If already installed same version software in system, Again installing time how to get Repair, Remove and Uninstall Options, If newer version is going to install same software how to get Upgrade options through Install shield.....

Comment: This is a really broad question.  I suggest you read the MSI SDK topics on Patching and Upgrading. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's built in.   If the PackageCode hasn't changed ( default is to change it with each build ) you'll get "Maintenance" UI experience.  ( Repari, Remove, Change )

If PackageCode has changed ( you did a new build ) you'll either get.....

If ProductCode has changed it'll look like a new install.  If the Upgrade  table is authored correctly, it'll do a Major Upgrade.

If ProductCode has not changed,  you'll get an error message saying another product is already installed.   If you have Setup.exe and the correct upgrade option selected it will do a Minor Upgrade.

Comment: ok.. minor upgrade means changing major and minor build version by visual studio(I am using ) under build properties and same thing I need to change build version in Install shield, Is it correct...

Comment: Your exe's and dll's should always have a greater file version (AssemblyFileVersion ) with each build regardless of what you do in InstallShield.    In InstallShield, your ProductVersion should be greater with each build.  If doing Major Upgrades you must increment one of the first three fields.  The fourth field is ignored and will not cause an upgrade.

Comment: First I will generate binaries from Visual Studio debug folder and after generated binaries Put into InstallSheild again going to build Setup.exe through basic MSI installer, Then Iam facing problem with If Old version software is already present then Add,Remove and Repair options are not getting and If new version is installing time not Upgrading prevoius software... For this problem can give the solution for it.